# Sessions or database access to check if user is logged in?

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I use php-sessions to check if users are logged in to my app. Is it significantly better for performance than just keeping the user id in a session and checking against the database if the user is logged in instead?

If the password changes or I want to block/log out a user it is easy to just change the database record, but when it lives in a session, can I do that? How?

Comment: Surely you only keep a boolean in the session like `$_SESSION['is_logged_in') = true;` right. Not the password

Comment: If you start mixing database stuff with sessions then you run the risk of race conditions.

Comment: You need to assess your threat model. What is the purpose of invalidating a user's session if they change their password?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Maybe he means they've scrambled the user's password to prevent him from logging in, but if they're already logged in that doesn't help.

Comment: No, I don't store the password. But if a user is logged in on one computer and changes the password on another he will still be logged in on the first computer. Also I want to be able to log out any user or change their permission, which I can't if it's stored in a session.

Comment: @SeaBass If you have specific functionality in mind then it's not a debate of what is "better" but rather which solution helps you to achieve your goal. In any case, this question is far too broad for this site.

Comment: If you are using the database session storage you can log out the user with deleting the row with the session id, if you are using the default file storage for session you can delete the file for that session

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I would change so that the logged in check happens in the database, I just assumed it is better for perfomance to not do that check for every single request and store it in a session. However, is it possible to update or invalidating user sessions with that model?

Comment: Now that I think of it, .NET Identity framework uses Security Stamp for such cases. It is a field in the identity user table which is changed if any security parameter changes. Then it will be used to invalidate sessios with invalid stamp. Something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both.

Use the session variable as a first check, so that you immediately reject any request where the session variable is not set. This saves doing a costly database check for random door-knocking requests.

But if it's set, you still have to do a database check to see if the user's login session is still valid. When a user logs in, create a random token and store it in a session variable and the database. When processing a new request, check if the session variable matches what's in the DB. If an admin wants to force a user to be logged out, they simply invalidate this database record.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need a random token/separate database table if I already have a user row with an ID to match with?

Comment: You can't use the user ID, because it has to change with every session. You can add it as a column to an existing table.

Comment: Makes sense. Any suggestions what field type, length and value to store? Some $_SESSION id generated by the server?

Comment: Oh and one more thing. I guess the separate table is fir multiple valid logins? With just one field in the user table you can only be logged in on one device at a time right? Any ideas about that?

Comment: A 32-character random string should be perfectly fine. If you want to allow multiple logins you can use a separate table, with a FK to the user table.

Answer (score 0):

> I use php-sessions to check if users are logged in to my app

I'm not sure exactly what that looks like - but it sounds horrendous. Either you've broken the session security model or you must be brute-forcing the session data every time you want to find out whom is logged in. Certainly a requirement to maintain a list of active sessions and user identifiers would be best implemented piggy-backed on a custom session handler (for the purposes of triggering - not for a common storage substrate) but you seem to be implying that you you are not doing this.

> If the password changes

You **cannot** keep the password used to authenticate the session in the session.

Comment: I think he means the server application checks the session variable to determine if the request came from a logged-in user. He's not talking about an admin listing all the users.